# Strange while loop. Puzzled

Tags: c

Novice in c programming. Could someone help me understand what the while loop is doing in this code snippet? I've never seen a while loop of this type.

However, I do understand that it is performing pointer arithmetic, but what is it actually saying broken down in terms of pseudocode or plain English? :)

```
char*
cpy (char* s)
{
  char *dest, *d;

  d = dest = malloc(strlen(s) * sizeof(char) + 1);

  if (d)
    while ((*d++ = *s++));
  return dest;
}
```

Comment: I believe it is copying a string from one source to another. It is doing so character for character. It is doing a lot in a single line. It is setting *d to whatever is at *s and incrementing them both to the next character. When it finally gets to the null character (end of the string), it returns it causing the while loop to end.

Comment: Did you read this in the k&r book?  You're better off calling `memcpy` to copy a string

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @self This might not be OP's implementation, it might just be an example they saw and wanted help understanding. I agree just using `memcpy` would make it easier, but I think this is more about trying to get a grasp on certain syntax. __edit:__ also `strcpy` is a thing

Comment: @ChrisSprague Exactly. It is not my code. I was just trying to get a grasp of the syntax, which was foreign to me.

Comment: @Olaf Who said anything about debugging the code? Nor was it implied that the code isn't working. Maybe you misread the post?

Comment: That's all what you read from the comment? Well, re-read it then! This is no tutoring or "explain the code" site.

Comment: @Olaf Did I ask for a tutorial?

Comment: ESL, but to me it sounds exactly like that.

Comment: @Olaf: How does it not fit this criterium?: 

Ask about...

    Specific programming problems
    Software algorithms
    Coding techniques
    Software development tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C a value of 0 means false and any other means true. Strings end in a null character with a value of 0.  This while loop copies all the characters from s to d until the null (end of string) is reached.

The assignment `*d++ = *s++` returns the same value as `*s++` is assigned to `*d`

After the loop both `s` and `d` will be pointing after the null character. Note that the null is also copied.

Comment: So this is also an assignment operation?

Comment: Yes, and the function is making a copy of the input string on the heap and returning a pointer to that new string. The caller must remember to free it otherwise it will leak.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `*d++ = *s++` actually returns a value. And it will go until it finds a byte: `\0` which when put into the while condition, will be zero and will jump to the next statement: the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Psuedo-code:

```
if dest is not null initially:
    keep a pointer to the current character in "s" and "d".
    (copy step) copy the current character in "s" to the same position in "d"
    move the pointer to the next character in "d" and "s"
    if the character copied in "copy step" was not '\0' or null:
        jump back to "copy step"
    otherwise:
        break out of loop
```

Comment: Correct except that pointers `s` and `d` are moved to the next character even if the character copied *was* `'\0'` (although the loop does end after)... unless the compiler decides to skip the last increment, I suppose.

Comment: @Dmitri P.S. if we're talking what the compiler is going to do to the code, this answer would be a heck of a lot different ;)